# Difference between "function" and "operation"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences, nouns, word-usage

Which one of the following is correct?

> Instructions given by the Vice Principal on behalf of the Principal for smooth function of the school must be followed by all staff members.

or

> Instructions given by the Vice Principal on behalf of the Principal for smooth operation of the school must be followed by all staff members.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[Operation](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/operation)** is best.  The *[function](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/function)* of a school would mean basically the *purpose* of the school, which cannot be "smooth".  *Operation* would mean *how things go* (how the function is accomplished), so the *operation* of the school is what can and should go "smoothly".

Also see PLL's comment below: *functioning* instead of *function* would easily suffice as a substitute for *operation* in most cases.  So your choices are between "operation" and "functioning" here.

Comment: This answer is perfect, but I just want to add that an operation exists to accomplish a function. A function is no more than a purpose or even goal of an organization.

Comment: How's the edit?

Comment: This is true, but it’s worth noting that while *function* is rather different, *functioning* can be rather more equivalent to *operation* in meaning, and “…for the smooth functioning of the school…” would be fine and quite idiomatic here.  [Google Ngrams comparison](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=smooth+functioning%2Csmooth+operation&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)

Answer (score 1):

The two words do have distinct meaning, and in this case, **operation** would be the correct word to use in that context.

The word `function` describes the intent and purpose of a thing. In the case of a school, the school's "function" is to serve as a place of teaching by the resident staff for the edification of and learning by the resident students. A purpose and intent lacks any real connotation of how well it might actually operate, it is a definition.

The word `operation` describes the performance and implementation of the function of a thing. In the case of a school, the school's "operation" is the act of teaching the students by the staff. A smoothly operating school performs its function well...a poorly operating school performs its function badly.

Answer (score 0):

*Operation* can be used to mean:

- a business organization; a company
- an activity in which such an organization is involved
- a piece of organized and concerted activity involving a number of people

The sentence is referring to an organized activity that involves more than one person; *operation* is the word that I would use, in this case.